# QGIS organising columns

Tags: qgis

After opening attribute table, and right click the column header, I get a prompt to organise columns.

Expected: clicking and dragging a column on top of another would put it on top

Actual: column goes way under

Is there another way of organising columns in QGIS ?

This is happening on QGIS 3.4, 3.8 and even on 3.10

Edit: this is on mac version as people in the office use mac

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem on 3.4.3 (windows 7 64bit), when I select organize columns I get a window with all the column in original order if I click and drag a column up or down I can see a black line showing where the column will end if I release the mouse (if you move to the right the line is easier to see). You may try to restart QGIS, restart your computer, or reinstalling QGIS. If the problem persist give more details as it is it's hard to help you more.

Answer (score 3):

The "savest" (and in my opinion best) way is to use `refactor fields` tool from processing toolbox. It creates a new layer based on your original layer and your settings.

[image]

Select the column you want to move or edit and use the arrows on the right or edit field properties.

Comment: Well like it says on the right side, original layer is not modified. Users doing this and making edits won't be able to update the original table?

Comment: Not this way. The only option is to overwrite the original layer.

Comment: Well I will give you an upvote but not the tick. People need to update the table and have a better layout at the same time. Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

This issue does not occur in Windows. It works for me in QGIS 3.4.10 on Windows 10, the same as J.R. described in their comment:

> on 3.4.3 (windows 7 64bit), when I select organize columns I get a window with all the column in original order if I click and drag a column up or down I can see a black line showing where the column will end if I release the mouse (if you move to the right the line is easier to see)

It sounds like you have a Mac-specific bug. It doesn't look like anyone has reported this bug yet. If you want it fixed you should report it: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues